# Adding new data to the neo4j graph database

Tags: import, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jrestclient

I am importing a huge dataset of about 46K nodes into Neo4j using import option.Now this dataset is dynamic i.e new entries keep getting adding to it now and then so  if i have to re perform the entire import then its wastage of resources.I tried using neo4j rest client of python to send the queries to create the new data points but as the number of new data points increase the time taken is more than the importing of 46k nodes.So is there any alternative to add these datapoints or do i have to redo the entire import?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - 46k is rather tiny.

The most easy way to import data into Neo4j is using `LOAD CSV` togesther with `PERIODIC COMMIT`. http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/ contains all the details.

Be sure to have indexes in place to find the stuff that needs to be changed with an incremental update quickly.

Comment: 46 K nodes is just for a trial but later i will have a few billion nodes then if there is a new addition of 10 or 20 nodes what do I do? Recreate the entire DB or any other alternative?